# Time periods merge by priority algorithm

Tags: time, asp-classic

I'm stuck trying to develop an algorithm for resolving time periods with different priority in classic ASP.

Is there any way to resolve time period overlapped by higher priority period (without resolving priority in every day)?

--

example input:

```
periodId(0) = 0: startDate(0) = dateValue("15-01-01"): endDate(0) = dateValue("15-03-31")    
periodId(1) = 1: startDate(1) = dateValue("15-01-18"): endDate(1) = dateValue("15-02-08")    
periodId(2) = 2: startDate(2) = dateValue("15-02-02"): endDate(2) = dateValue("15-02-16")    
periodId(3) = 3: startDate(3) = dateValue("15-01-29"): endDate(3) = dateValue("15-02-05")    
periodId(4) = 4: startDate(4) = dateValue("15-03-01"): endDate(4) = dateValue("15-03-08")
```

--

example output:

```
resolvedId(0) = 0: resolvedStart(0) = "15-01-01": resolvedEnd(0) = "15-01-17"    
resolvedId(1) = 1: resolvedStart(1) = "15-01-18": resolvedEnd(1) = "15-01-28"    
resolvedId(2) = 3: resolvedStart(2) = "15-01-29": resolvedEnd(2) = "15-02-05"    
resolvedId(3) = 2: resolvedStart(3) = "15-02-06": resolvedEnd(3) = "15-02-16"    
resolvedId(4) = 0: resolvedStart(4) = "15-02-17": resolvedEnd(4) = "15-02-28"    
resolvedId(5) = 4: resolvedStart(5) = "15-03-01": resolvedEnd(5) = "15-03-08"    
resolvedId(6) = 0: resolvedStart(6) = "15-03-09": resolvedEnd(6) = "15-03-31"
```

example in graphic:

[image: Example Output]

...any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

----- EDIT 15-03-13 -----

I need array as output - image was only for better understanding. I need arrays with dates as output...

I developed algorithm:

```
<%' ....
i = 0
while not objRS.Eof
    redim preserve periodId(i)  'integer
    redim preserve startDate(i)  'date
    redim preserve endDate(i)    'date

    'DB parse
    periodId(i) = objRS("idc")
    periodStartDateIn(i) = DateValue(objRS("tempDatumStart"))
    periodEndDateIn(i)   = DateValue(objRS("tempDatumKonec"))

    'date limit detection
    if periodStartDateIn(i) < resolvedMinDate then resolvedMinDate = periodStartDateIn(i)
    if periodEndDateIn(i)   > resolvedMaxDate then resolvedMaxDate = periodEndDateIn(i)

    i = i + 1
    objRs.moveNext
wend

lastIndex = -1
redim preserve resolvedIndex(0)
redim preserve resolvedStartDate(0)
redim preserve resolvedEndDate(0)
for dateActual = resolvedMinDate to resolvedMaxDate
    for index = lbound(periodId) to ubound(periodId)
        if periodStartDateIn(index) <= dateActual and dateActual <= periodEndDateIn(index) then
            IndexActual = index
            exit for
        end if
    next

    if IndexActual <> lastIndex then
        if lastIndex <> -1 then 'not first pass
            redim preserve resolvedIndex(ubound(resolvedIndex) + 1)
            redim preserve resolvedStartDate(ubound(resolvedStartDate) + 1)
            redim preserve resolvedEndDate(ubound(resolvedEndDate) + 1)
            resolvedEndDate(ubound(resolvedEndDate)-1) = dateActual - 1 'close prev period
        end if
        resolvedIndex(ubound(resolvedIndex)) = IndexActual
        resolvedStartDate(ubound(resolvedStartDate)) = dateActual
    end if
    lastIndex = IndexActual
next
resolvedEndDate(ubound(resolvedEndDate)) = dateActual - 1

'...
%>
```

...but it checks every date in interval. This should take quite long time to resolve in case of many periods and few year-decades between startDate and endDate...

...is there any algorith to solve it analytic way?

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a design issue. You need to sit down with a pencil and paper and work out the potential situations that can be encountered. The key things here are where your times can overlap:

```
     _______________________________
    |<Start Time           End Time>|   <-- Comparable time range

|<Start Time           End Time>|

        |<Start Time           End Time>|

        |<Start Time   End Time>|

|<Start Time                   End Time>|
```

There are other things to consider here, as well, such as no start (x)or end time.

As for the output, I would consider writing the output to `div`s that have relative positioning, and simply set the `left` and `width` CSS attributes.